# How to cache token with Microsoft Graph for Java

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-graph-sdks, azure-identity

I am using Microsoft Graph SDK for some requests however everytime I perform a GET request it does another request to get a token. I've tried reading documentation about this but I cannot find anything in Java.

Here is my implementation of my client

```java
         ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
            .clientId(clientId)
            .clientSecret(clientSecret)
            .tenantId(tenantId)
            .httpClient(httpClient)
            .build();
```

I have also tried using the method `.tokenCachePersistenceOptions()` in my builder but I get this warning/error

```
c.m.a.m.CrossProcessCacheFileLock        : null
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the above requirement *Firstly you need to Authenticate for implementing MSAL to get the token from Azure AD*.

To obtain an access token, your app must be registered with the Microsoft identity platform and approved to access the Microsoft Graph resources it requires by either a user who is added as an owner for that application or an administrator.

For complete setup please refer this MS DOCUMENT [***Authentication and authorization basics for Microsoft Graph***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts) , [***This sample***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/java) & [***GitHub sample|msgraph-sdk-java-core***](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java-core/tree/dev/samples%2FdeviceCodeSample)

Comment: Thank you I will try this in the next days

Comment: You are welcome:) ..Any update on this @XavierChopin

Comment: I've got an answer on github by the SDK engineers they told me they reproduce the bug on their own and they will fix it

Comment: Could you please post the resolution here .

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same think and here's what I've implemented for it:

Implement your own authentication provider class:

```
public class DelegateAuthenticationProvider implements IAuthenticationProvider {
    private String token;

    public DelegateAuthenticationProvider(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public CompletableFuture<String> getAuthorizationTokenAsync(@NotNull URL url) {
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(token);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it as follow:

```
String token = "<YOUR_TOKEN_STRING>"
IAuthenticationProvider tokenCredentialAuthProvider = new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(token);

// Create the Graph Client with the given Token Provider
GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder()
        .authenticationProvider(tokenCredentialAuthProvider)
        .buildClient();
```

If you get an *GraphServiceException* code *401* you should renew your token.

When you are successfully logged in with your clientSecretCredential, here's how you can get the token:

```
List<String> scopes = Arrays.asList("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");
IAuthenticationProvider tokenCredentialAuthProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(scopes, clientSecretCredential);
String token = tokenCredentialAuthProvider.getAuthorizationTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me").get()
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the authenticationProvider which is provided for the GraphServiceClient

```
import com.azure.core.credential.AccessToken;
import com.azure.core.credential.TokenCredential;
import com.azure.core.credential.TokenRequestContext;
import com.microsoft.graph.authentication.TokenCredentialAuthProvider;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.net.URL;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public class CachingTokenCredentialAuthProvider extends TokenCredentialAuthProvider {
    private final TokenCredential tokenCredential;
    private final TokenRequestContext context;
    private AccessToken accessToken;

    public CachingTokenCredentialAuthProvider(@NotNull List<String> scopes, @NotNull TokenCredential tokenCredential) {
        super(scopes, tokenCredential);
        if (!scopes.isEmpty()) {
            this.context = new TokenRequestContext();
            this.context.setScopes(scopes);
            this.tokenCredential = Objects.requireNonNull(tokenCredential, "tokenCredential parameter cannot be null.");
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("scopes parameter cannot be null or empty");
        }
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public CompletableFuture<String> getAuthorizationTokenAsync(@NotNull URL requestUrl) {
        if (this.shouldAuthenticateRequestWithUrl(Objects.requireNonNull(requestUrl, "requestUrl parameter cannot be null"))) {
            if(this.accessToken != null && !OffsetDateTime.now().minusMinutes(1).isAfter(this.accessToken.getExpiresAt())) {
                return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(this.accessToken.getToken());
            }

            return this.tokenCredential.getToken(this.context).toFuture().thenApply(accessToken -> {
                saveToken(accessToken);
                return accessToken.getToken();
            });
        } else {
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
        }
    }

    void saveToken(AccessToken accessToken) {
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
    }
}
```

This will cache the token until it one minute before it is no longer valid.